# How to override Chakra UI default CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, chakra-ui

I have this Chakra UI component:

```
<Tag
   variant={'outline'}
   cursor={'pointer'}
   outline={'none'}
   className={`${styles.editProfileAvatarIconCamera} ri-camera-line`}
></Tag>
```

Which renders an outlined camera icon like this

[image]

Now I'd like to remove the outline. I tried to add `outline={'none'}` like the above, but it didn't work. In console I can see that Chakra CSS is always in the highest priority and overrides all other CSS.

How can I apply this custom CSS to the `Tag` component? I tried importing a SCSS file, but it's the same, overridden by Chakra default CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can see there is a `box-shadow` not an `outline`:

```
<Tag
   variant={'outline'}
   cursor={'pointer'}
   boxShadow={'none'}
   className={`${styles.editProfileAvatarIconCamera} ri-camera-line`}
></Tag>
```